# Many categorical variable at the same time in Matrix

Tags: r

I've collected data as follow :

```
            A       B          C       D      E        F                 G

  1         1       0          0       0      0        0                 0
  1,2       0       1          0       0      0        0                 2
  1,2,3     0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
  1,3       0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
  2         0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
  2,3       4       0          0       0      5        0                 0
  3         1       3          0       0      0        2                 0
  4         0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
```

For each Color (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) it corresponds to one or many category at the same time(1,2,3,4) according sample.  For many category, there is comma separation.

I want to simplify my data to have it as follows :

```
            A       B          C       D      E        F                 G

  1         1       1          0       0      0        0                 2
  3         4       0          0       0      5        2                 0
  2         4       1          0       0      5        0                 2
  4         0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
```

is there a simple way (function) to do this ?

Reproducible example :

```
DF <- read.table(text = " Color         Cat

A             1
B             1   
C             4,2
D             1,3
E             1,2
F             3
G             5
A             2
B             3   
C             1,2
D             4,3
E             3
F             1
G             1" , header = TRUE)

DF = table(DF$Cat,DF$Color)
cats <- strsplit(rownames(DF), ",", fixed = TRUE)
DF <- DF[rep(seq_len(nrow(DF)), sapply(cats, length)),]
DF$cat <- unlist(cats)
DF <- aggregate(. ~ cat, DF, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: can you dput your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "            A       B          C       D      E        F                 G
                 1         1       0          0       0      0        0                 0
                 1,2       0       1          0       0      0        0                 2
                 1,2,3     0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
                 1,3       0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
                 2         0       0          0       0      0        0                 0
                 2,3       4       0          0       0      5        0                 0
                 3         1       3          0       0      0        2                 0
                 4         0       0          0       0      0        0                 0", header = TRUE)

#split the row names
cats <- strsplit(rownames(DF), ",", fixed = TRUE)
#repeat each row of the DF times the number of cats
DF <- DF[rep(seq_len(nrow(DF)), sapply(cats, length)),]
#add column with cats
DF$cat <- unlist(cats)
#aggregate (your question is unclear regarding how)
DF <- aggregate(. ~ cat, DF, FUN = sum) #or FUN = max???
#  cat A B C D E F G
#1   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2
#2   2 4 1 0 0 5 0 2
#3   3 5 3 0 0 5 2 0
#4   4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm looking for the sum. I've a problem with k$cat <- unlist(cats) : automatic conversion of LHS to LIST. I've obtained my table of frequency through table() function. Is it the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Use `DF <- as.data.frame(unclass(DF))` to make your table a data.frame.